# Decode json android

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am having a hard time to decode my json data.Please help.Here is my code:
This is how my json looks:

```
[
   {"0":"6","ID":"6","1":"USA","Country":"USA","2":"1","Age":"1","3":"Type 5","Type":"Type 5","4":"Brand5","Brands":"Brand5","5":"ashfghdfhhgfdhhdfhhdfg\t\t\t\t\t\t","Contents":"ashfghdfhhgfdhhdfhhdfg\t\t\t\t\t\t","6":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","Time":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},
   {"0":"7","ID":"7","1":"Europe","Country":"Europe","2":"1","Age":"1","3":"Type 5","Type":"Type 5","4":"Brand5","Brands":"Brand5","5":"\t\t\t\tafsfsdgfgh\t\t\t\t\t","Contents":"\t\t\t\tafsfsdgfgh\t\t\t\t\t","6":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","Time":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},
   {"0":"9","ID":"9","1":"USA","Country":"USA","2":"4","Age":"4","3":"Type3","Type":"Type3","4":"Brand4","Brands":"Brand4","5":"sfdsggfhgfhfhg\t\t","Contents":"sfdsggfhgfhfhg\t\t","6":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","Time":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},
   {"0":"10","ID":"10","1":"Europe","Country":"Europe","2":"6","Age":"6","3":"Type3","Type":"Type3","4":"Brand4","Brands":"Brand4","5":"\t\t\t\t\tsfgfdgfhhgfdhghg\t\t\t","Contents":"\t\t\t\t\tsfgfdgfhhgfdhghg\t\t\t","6":"2011-06-03 16:07:08","Time":"2011-06-03 16:07:08"}
]
```

This is my class:

```
public class Foo {

@SerializedName("0")
public String zero;

@SerializedName("ID")
public String ID;

@SerializedName("1")
public String unu;

@SerializedName("Country")
public String Country;

@SerializedName("2")
public String doi;

@SerializedName("Age")
public String Age;

@SerializedName("3")
public String trei;

@SerializedName("Type")
public String Type;

@SerializedName("4")
public String patru;

@SerializedName("Brands")
public String Brands;

@SerializedName("5")
public String cinci;

@SerializedName("Contents")
public String Contents;

@SerializedName("6")
public String sase;

@SerializedName("Time")
public String Time;
  }
```

This is my class list of type Foo:

```
public class FooList {

public List<Foo> listFoo;

}
```

And this is how i try do decode it:

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type fooType=new TypeToken<FooList>() { }.getType();
        FooList vaccines=gson.fromJson(json, fooType);
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
FooList vaccines = gson.fromJson(json, FooList.class);
```

What error/exception are you getting?

**UPDATE:**

The problem is that you are trying to decode a `List` of items to an object that contains a list of items. If you want to decode into `FooList` then your JSON string should look like this:

```
{ "listFoo":
  [
    {"0":"6","ID":"6","1":"USA","Country":"USA","2":"1","Age":"1","3":"Type 5","Type":"Type 5","4":"Brand5","Brands":"Brand5","5":"ashfghdfhhgfdhhdfhhdfg\t\t\t\t\t\t","Contents":"ashfghdfhhgfdhhdfhhdfg\t\t\t\t\t\t","6":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","Time":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},
    {"0":"7","ID":"7","1":"Europe","Country":"Europe","2":"1","Age":"1","3":"Type 5","Type":"Type 5","4":"Brand5","Brands":"Brand5","5":"\t\t\t\tafsfsdgfgh\t\t\t\t\t","Contents":"\t\t\t\tafsfsdgfgh\t\t\t\t\t","6":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","Time":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},
    {"0":"9","ID":"9","1":"USA","Country":"USA","2":"4","Age":"4","3":"Type3","Type":"Type3","4":"Brand4","Brands":"Brand4","5":"sfdsggfhgfhfhg\t\t","Contents":"sfdsggfhgfhfhg\t\t","6":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","Time":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},
    {"0":"10","ID":"10","1":"Europe","Country":"Europe","2":"6","Age":"6","3":"Type3","Type":"Type3","4":"Brand4","Brands":"Brand4","5":"\t\t\t\t\tsfgfdgfhhgfdhghg\t\t\t","Contents":"\t\t\t\t\tsfgfdgfhhgfdhghg\t\t\t","6":"2011-06-03 16:07:08","Time":"2011-06-03 16:07:08"}
  ]
}
```

If you have no choice but to work with the JSON string you've provided, then you could possibly make something like this work:

```
List listOfObjects = g.fromJson(json, List.class);

for(Object obj : listOfObjects) {
  FooList.listFoo.add((Foo) obj);
}
```

Comment: Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expecting array but found object: com.imc.vaccines.fooList@43d4eb00

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it.  The following examples all deserialize and run as expected.

**Deserialize into a Foo array:**

```
public class Foo
{
  @SerializedName("0")
  String zero;

  @SerializedName("ID")
  String ID;

  @SerializedName("1")
  String unu;

  @SerializedName("Country")
  String Country;

  @SerializedName("2")
  String doi;

  @SerializedName("Age")
  String Age;

  @SerializedName("3")
  String trei;

  @SerializedName("Type")
  String Type;

  @SerializedName("4")
  String patru;

  @SerializedName("Brands")
  String Brands;

  @SerializedName("5")
  String cinci;

  @SerializedName("Contents")
  String Contents;

  @SerializedName("6")
  String sase;

  @SerializedName("Time")
  String Time;

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format(
        "{Foo: zero=%s, ID=%s, unu=%s, Country=%s, doi=%s, Age=%s, trei=%s, Type=%s, patru=%s, Brands=%s, cinci=%s, Contents=%s, sase=%s, Time=%s}", 
        zero, ID, unu, Country, doi, Age, trei, Type, patru, Brands, cinci, Contents, sase, Time);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Foo[] foos = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), Foo[].class);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(foos));
  }
}
```

**Deserialize into a List of Foo:**

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listOfFooType = new TypeToken<List<Foo>>(){}.getType();
    List<Foo> foos = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), listOfFooType);
    System.out.println(foos);
  }
```

**Deserialize into a FooList using Tanner's changed JSON:**

```
public class Foo
{
  ...


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    FooList fooList = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), FooList.class);
    System.out.println(fooList.listFoo);
  }
}

class FooList
{
  List<Foo> listFoo;
}
```